# C# PowerPoint VSTO Addin: Change superscript font style after added text in PowerPoint TextRange

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, powerpoint-addins

In one of my C# PowerPoint VSTO Addins, I have added some text in superscript at the current cursor location in a shape's TextRange like this

```
PowerPoint.TextRange superscriptText = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.InsertAfter("xyz");
superscriptText.Font.Superscript = Office.MsoTriState.msoCTrue;
```

This works as intended: the string "xyz" is inserted in superscript at the current cursor location. The problem is that once "xyz" is inserted, the font style is still in superscript for all text that follows i.e., text that the user types at the cursor after inserting the "xyz". How can I change the tex style at the cursor back to being non-superscripted after inserting superscripted text? I have unsuccessfully tried with

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Superscript = Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
```

But further typed text still continues in superscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. You can,  work with the `InsertAfter` (and `InsertBefore`) methods in combination with the required formatting.

**The formatting is appended to the `InsertAfter` method**:

```
PowerPoint.TextRange superscriptText = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange;
superscriptText.InsertAfter("xyz").Font.Superscript = Office.MsoTriState.msoCTrue;
superscriptText.InsertAfter(" not superscript").Font.Superscript = Office.MsoTriState.msoCFalse;
```

2. Create a second `TextRange` object when using `InsertAfter`. The language reference states:

> Appends a string to the end of the specified text range. Returns a
>   TextRange object that represents the appended text.

**Create a new `TextRange` and format it separately**

```
PowerPoint.TextRange superscriptText = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange;
superscriptText.InsertAfter("xyz")
superscriptText.Font.Superscript = Office.MsoTriState.msoCTrue;
PowerPoint.TextRange normalText = superscriptText.InsertAfter(" not superscript")
normalText.Font.Superscript = Office.MsoTriState.msoCFalse;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This certainly works if I want to add more text programatically, but my question was referred to User input i.e., the function is called during runtime while someone is working with PowerPoint. After the subscript text is inserted correctly, the user can still type in the same textbox (directly in ppt). The problem is that all text that is entered by the user is still superscripted. My current workaround is to insert a single space (not superscripted) after the superscripted text. I am wondering if it could be done without the space.

Comment: @Ruehri That wasn't really clear in the question, but... This is the way the application is designed to work (and Word is the same). If the user types superscript, it will keep typing superscript until the font setting is changed; code works the same way. What's appended simply adapts the formatting of the adjacent text run until that's explicitly changed. There's nothing that can be done to change that, except to proceed as you're already doing (add a non-superscript space).

Comment: thanks a lot for the help and patience. Sorry if it was not 100% clear in the question. Maybe just one more follow-up question before I mark this as accepted: during runtime (directly in powerpoint) one can change the font style directly after superscripted text and continue typing non-superscripted text. That is what I was trying to do with Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Superscript = Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse; (to set the style at cursor to non-superscripted). I wonder why it isn't working or if there is no workaround?

Comment: @Ruehri If the selection doesn't contain any characters, there's basically nothing it's being applied *to*, so there's nothing to "hold" it - It's lost. This is just the way Word and PowerPoint are designed...

Comment: Ok thanks, got it. It still feels weird if you look at Word's Insert Footnote function for example. There, it is perfectly fine to insert a superscript text (the footnote reference number) and then when you immediately continue typing after the superscripted number it is without superscript. I have marked this as answered nonetheless and will continue with the "it is not possible" answer...

Comment: @Ruehri Ah, but there you're dealing with the proprietary Word application, and Microsoft allows itself to do things to which the lowly non-MS developers have no access :-) If you take a close look at footnote references with the display of non-printing characters turned on you'll see: 1) a little dotted box around the number, isolating it from the rest of the text; 2) a *space* character following in the footnote text. But the little dotted box is doing the trick for Microsoft :-) And if you were to look at the underlying Word Open XML you'd see there's a lot of information stored "in" it :-)

Comment: Yep, there's certainly a lot going on in that box! :) Quite weird that MS is not implementing a similar feature for PowerPoint. It would open up a new "toy" for developers to play with and I figure it would also be quite useful for ppt users as well. Maybe in a future version... Thanks again for your very helpful and elaborate support on this question!